# Frequency table to calculate and sort the sum of elements contained in an array

Tags: r, sorting, frequency

I have a table that lists participants, the app they were using on their phones, and the duration of each session. It looks like this:

```
  panelist_id                        app_name duration
1       550302                        Messages  10 secs
3       550302                          Google   2 secs
5       550302 com.google.android.partnersetup  20 secs
7       550302                          Google   8 secs
9       550302                          Google  30 secs
11      550302                          Dialer   8 secs
```

I want to tabulate the above to inspect total time spent on an app by participant. So hopefully it should like this:

```
                 55302 550303 55304                        
1       Messages  1040  1000   458                    
3       Google    900   580    345                    
5       Dialer    800   150    340
7       Facebook  513   1549   418
```

The number of apps is more than 5000 and there are 100 users so manually inserting the column and row names is not an option.

I have tried achieving this by building a frequency table but it didn't get me very far.

This is my first time posting a question so apologies for any mistakes and thanks in advance!

Comment: The other question you suggest is very similar indeed but does not provide any info on how to sort by two different variables. Using the same code I get an issue of "arguments must have same length".

Answer (score 0):

Using [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) you could write something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(app_name, panelist_id) %>% summarize(total_duration = sum(duration))
```

Comment: Thanks! What I get back looks like this:

                                   app_name panelist_id total_duration
                                     <fctr>       <int> <S3: difftime>
1      #SquareDroid \\u2014 Full Size Photo      598136        18 secs
2  &micro;Torrent&reg; - Torrent Downloader      590543      1372 secs

In the current form however I get duplicate entries of both apps and panelists making it hard to analyse afterwards. Hopefully I could extract it into a csv afterwards to analyse.